# muQueue.front() gives const instance even though I didn't mark it const

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem in this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
int main()
{
    class Buffer{
        public:
        void consumed(size_t s) {
            //alter something inside Buffer
        }
    };

    std::queue<Buffer> bufferFifo;
    typedef std::function<void()> Task;
    std::queue<Task> tasks;
    auto b = bufferFifo.front();
    tasks.emplace([b]() {
            b.consumed(0);
        });
}
```

The error that I'm getting on my program is this:

error: 'this' argument to member function 'consumed' has type 'const libopenvpn::Buffer<unsigned char *, libopenvpn::GenericObjectHolder>', but function is not marked const
b.consumed(r->size());

but the error I get when I created this minimum viable example on an online compier: http://cpp.sh/9zksg is this:

```
 In lambda function:
20:25: error: passing 'const main()::Buffer' as 'this' argument of 'void main()::Buffer::consumed(size_t)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

which I believe is the same error. Looks like that somehow, `b` is being marked as `const` even though I didn't make it const anywhere.

Why it is const?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, any variables captured by value in a lambda are `const`.

If you mark the lambda as `mutable` then the captured `b` is no longer const:

```
tasks.emplace( [b] () mutable {
       b.consumed(0);
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cCsryz).

Also, variables captured by reference are non-const, so you can just capture `b` by reference:

```
tasks.emplace( [&b] () {
       b.consumed(0);
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mngg3g)